# EFUtilities bulk InsertAll with children entities

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, bulkinsert

I am trying to bulk insert a list of items in my SQL Server by using the EFUtilities package. Is there a way i can insert an entity with multiple navigation properties? All i have found is this

```
EFBatchOperation.For(DbContext, DbContext.Products).InsertAll(batch);

EFBatchOperation.For(DbContext, DbContext.Categories).InsertAll(batch.SelectMany(p => p.Categories));

EFBatchOperation.For(DbContext, DbContext.Orders).InsertAll(batch.SelectMany(p => p.Orders));

DbContext.SaveChanges();
```

which saves the entities in my DB but the FK is always 0.For example The ID in my product table is 1 and in my categories table is 0. So this way is not handling the mapping.

Comment: A normal Insert would update the children w/o any further action required. When InsertAll doesn't you will at least need a SaveChanges after the first line.  (not familiar with these utilities).

Comment: I have already tried adding DbContext.SaveChanges(); after the first line hoping that after all products get an ID, all foreign keys for categories and Orders will be assigned automatically. It doesn't work

Comment: The docs are pretty clear: "You cannot insert relationships this way".

Comment: I saw that but i was wondering as i saw this post from the creator https://github.com/MikaelEliasson/EntityFramework.Utilities/issues/42 if selectmany can work for my example

Comment: The issue is still open, and 3.5 years old...  Fixing it would probably hurt performance a lot. Cascading new keys is not easy or cheap.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented an extension to EFUtilities that allows bulk insert while also returning the generated IDs and setting them on the source objects. My version includes other improvement like better thread safety, and optional divide-and-conquer type retry for inserted sets.

There are two caveats though:

- Only Primary Keys of type `long` (`bigint`) are supported. The code would need adjustments to supports other types of columns.
- The navigation properties are not inserted automatically, you have to call `InsertAll` multiple times.

The code is too long to be included here in whole, it can be found in my blog: [Entity Framework 6 – Bulk Insert and Returning of Generated Primary Keys](https://kobikobi.wordpress.com/2018/02/05/entity-framework-6-bulk-insert-and-returning-of-generated-primary-keys/)

The most relevant part is this - inserting all data to a temporary table, and using `insert into` and [`output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to ensure data is inserted in the right order:

```
private static void BulkInsertAllAndReturnIds<T>(BulkInsertionCollectionMetadata<T> items, string schema,
    string tableName,
    IList<ColumnMapping> properties, SqlConnection connection, int? batchSize)
{
    if (items.Count == 0) return;
    long dummyValue = -1000 - items.Count;
    //set dummy IDs
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        ((IHasPrimaryKey)item).PrimaryKey = dummyValue;
        dummyValue++;
    }
    try
    {
        if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            connection.Open();
        }

        //create dummy table.
        using (var tempTable = new TempTable(connection, tableName, schema))
        {
            var createTempTableSql = $"Select * Into {tempTable.TableName} From {tableName} Where 1 = 2";
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(createTempTableSql, connection))
            {
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            //bulk insert to temp table.
            BulkInsertAll(items, schema, tempTable.TableName, properties, connection, batchSize,
                SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepNulls | SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity);

            //note: IsPrimaryKey is not populated in InsertAll 
            // https://github.com/MikaelEliasson/EntityFramework.Utilities/blob/a5abc50b7367d64ca541b6e7e2e6018a500b6d8d/EntityFramework.Utilities/EntityFramework.Utilities/EFBatchOperation.cs#L129

            string primaryKeyNameOnObject = ((IHasPrimaryKey)items.First()).PrimaryKeyPropertyName;
            var primaryKey = properties.Single(c => c.NameOnObject == primaryKeyNameOnObject);
            var otherColumns = properties.Where(p => p != primaryKey);
            var allValueColumns = String.Join(", ", otherColumns.Select(c => "[" + c.NameInDatabase + "]"));

            //insert to real table and get new IDs.
            //this guarantees the record IDs are generated in the right order.
            var migrateAndReturnIds =
                $@"
                insert into {tableName} ({allValueColumns})
                OUTPUT inserted.{primaryKey.NameInDatabase}
                select {allValueColumns} from {tempTable.TableName} temp
                order by temp.{primaryKey.NameInDatabase}
                ";

            var newlyGeneratedIds = new List<long>(items.Count);
            using (var migrateDataCommand = new SqlCommand(migrateAndReturnIds, connection)
            {
                CommandTimeout = 0
            })
            using (var recordIdReader = migrateDataCommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (recordIdReader.Read())
                {
                    var newId = recordIdReader.GetInt64(0);
                    newlyGeneratedIds.Add(newId);
                }
            }
            //set IDs on entities.
            if (newlyGeneratedIds.Count != items.Count)
            {
                throw new MissingPrimaryKeyException("There are fewer generated record IDs than the " +
                                                        "number of items inserted to the database.");
            }
            //the order of the IDs is not guaranteed, but the values will be generated in the same as the order values in `items`
            newlyGeneratedIds.Sort();
            for (int i = 0; i < newlyGeneratedIds.Count; i++)
            {
                ((IHasPrimaryKey)items[i]).PrimaryKey = newlyGeneratedIds[i];
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        //make sure the ID is 0 if the row wasn't inserted.
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var entity = (IHasPrimaryKey)item;
            if (entity.PrimaryKey < 0) entity.PrimaryKey = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

By the way - Unlike normal usage of Entity Framework, you don't need to call `SaveChanges()` after using bulk insets - `InsertAll` already saves the changes.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a library or a cs file i can use? Github or a nuget package maybe? I copy the code but there are multiple parts with syntax that my visual studio doesn't recognise like public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() => _items.GetEnumerator(); or new SqlCommand($"DROP table {_dbSchema}.[{TableName}]", _connection))

Comment: @DKar - These are string interpolation and method lambda bodies - both of them are C# 6.0 features. You can fix the first to `public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() { return _items.GetEnumerator();}` and second to `"DROP table " + _dbSchema + ...`.

Comment: @DKar - I didn't write it as a package because a better approach is to fork EFUtilities, and because I didn't know how useful it was anyway. I expect new project would use EF Core anyway - so I thought a blog post would be enough. A package is significantly more work, and would not allow users to tweak the code as needed (and I'm sure changes are required).

Comment: OK. I will have to fix them manually as my project doesn't support c# 6. I was wondering if there is an earlier version

Comment: I ve converted it to an earlier c# version, i am trying to use the BulkInsertAllAndReturnIds but i keep getting There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Base.DAL.DataProvider.MSSQL.Products' to 'Base.DAL.Helpers.IHasPrimaryKey'.

Comment: @DKar - You need to have `Product` implementing `IHasPrimaryKey`. On the same folder Product is defined, add a new file with `public partial class Product : IHasPrimaryKey{ ... }`;. This is explained nicely here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14445478/7586